# Data Tag For Dogs/Wolfs tail

Tags: minecraft-java-edition, minecraft-commands

I was messing around with conmand blocks and summoning tamed dogs. When I summon them, their tails are always down and they wimper and need food. What data tag would I add so their tail is up and I do not need to feed them?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The health of the wolf is what determines tail height. When not tame, its current and maximum health will be 8.0 (4 hearts). When the wolf is manually tamed by a player, both its current and maximum will become 20.0 (10 hearts).

However, there are a few issues with modifying the health of a wolf via `/summon`. When you summon the wolf pre-tamed, its `generic.maxHealth` attribute will initially be 8.0 as a result of instantiating a `Wolf` entity, meaning you cannot specify a higher current health. The game will not update its `maxHealth` to 20.0 until after being created. Since this update occurs after creation, its current health will remain at 8.0 from summoning.

The fix is to also specify a new `maxHealth` attribute value, but because this value change happens before its `maxHealth` is updated from being tame, any value you provide will be overwritten. **Note:** the `maxHealth` overwriting also occurs at all times after summoning, so you cannot use external mechanisms to change its maximum health; you'll need to use defensive methods such as the Resistance effect.

As such, the following will ensure the wolf will have the maximum health a wolf can have.

1.8:

```
/summon Wolf ~ ~1 ~ {Owner:"Skylinerw",HealF:20.0f,Attributes:[{Name:"generic.maxHealth",Base:20.0}]}
```

1.9:

```
/summon Wolf ~ ~1 ~ {Owner:"Skylinerw",Health:20.0f,Attributes:[{Name:"generic.maxHealth",Base:20.0}]}
```

Comment: What about summoning the wolf with active healing effect?

Comment: @AntoineHejlík Yep, that will work as well! `/summon Wolf ~ ~1 ~ {Owner:"Skylinerw",ActiveEffects:[{Id:6,Duration:20}]}`